# Ember data find vs load

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When you use findQuery in ember-data, does it also load the model localy ? I can't make the following code to work :

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend {

   name: DS.attr('string')
   didLoad: ->
    console.log('model loaded')
}
```

Now when I do something like :

```
objects = App.store.find(App.MyModel, [{name: "john"},{name: "jack"}])
```

The didLoad callback is not fired. When this callback is fired ?

Answer (score 1):

To implement the query functionality you have to implement the `findQuery` method in your adapter. This method takes 4 arguments `store, type, query, modelArray`. When the server returns the data for the query, you have to invoke the `load` method on the `modelArray` to fill it with the query result. This method also loads the data into the store, see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/5HMGd/.

```js
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 4,
    adapter: DS.Adapter.create({
        find: Ember.K,
        findQuery: function(store, type, query, modelArray) {
            // expect server to return this array
            modelArray.load([{ id: 1, name: 'John'}, { id: 2, name: 'Jack'}]);
        }
    })
});

App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    didLoad: function() {
        console.log('model loaded', this.toJSON());
    }
});

// invoke query which loads the 2 models, and didLoad is called
App.store.find(App.MyModel, {});
```

​